# Vue Tree flatten array or recursive component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Hi guys I'm trying to build Tree component in Vue, I'm having a little doubt now I have already built a recursive component, similar to this one, but more complex with checkboxes, drag drop etc

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/tree-view.html

But now I'm looking at some samples online and it looks of them are made by flattening nested json and making a Tree out of it

Like this one:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/fernando2684/p0k8szvj/43/
```

Hi here recursive builds array and then builds Tree out of it

```
   recursive(obj, newObj, level, itemId, isExpend) {
      let vm = this;

      obj.forEach(function(o) {
        if (o.children && o.children.length != 0) {
          o.level = level;
          o.leaf = false;
          newObj.push(o);
          if (o.id == itemId) {
            o.expend = isExpend;
          }
          if (o.expend == true) {
            vm.recursive(o.children, newObj, o.level + 1, itemId, isExpend);
          }
        } else {
          o.level = level;
          o.leaf = true;
          newObj.push(o);
          return false;
        }
      });
    },
```

Could someone tell, what could be real benefit out of this, I see it could be easier to maintain and  all the data in array is reactive since it is only in one level ???

Comment: My guess (based on Redux) is that flat object structure is easier to manage (imagine mutating nested object several levels deep)

Comment: Yes that was my guess because in Vue it tracks only one level deep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's a matter of optimizing the data for use in the template.

#### Flat array

If you're rendering a `table`, using recursive components will be difficult to implement.

If you have an array, you can pass it through a `v-for` and you end up with *a single component* that has all the children (no matter the depth) as direct children. This makes controlling actions easier.

#### Nested Object

But if you want to use `divs` that recursively indent, then using a flat array is more difficult.

If you were to use objects, you would have to use *recursive components* with their individual parent-child relationships that need to bubble up.

---

Do which ever suits you better, but don't think optimizing data for template is worse than creating more complex component relationships.

Comment: what do you mean by optimizing the data for use ? Which solution would you use recursive or with v-for ?

Comment: updated answer....  should be more clear. I wouldn't say one is better than the other, but both are better than the other in some cases.

Comment: The template rendering has logic that is abstracted from us, and sometimes it is tempting to use complex template directives to achieve a goal, when a (relatively simple) function to clean up the data may be more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: sorry to bother you, but if you have time could you alos check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60217438/implementing-tree-component-problem-with-checkboxes, because Im having a problem with selecting checkboxes I would be really gratefull :)